# No wp-admin, wp-config, or .htaccess folder/file

Tags: wp-admin, uploads, wp-config

This all started when I was not able to upload a picture to my site. All media under Media do not have their picture or preview; the pictures would simply be blank. Clicking on View while in list mode would return Internal Server error.

I decided to SFTP into the server to see what's going on. The server has the following structure, pretty regular for a Unix host.

[image: wp file structure]

There's no wp-admin, wp-config, .htaccess or anything. I can't make these folders despite being an admin.

The default media upload path is /nfs/c12/h07/mnt/224753/domains/sitename.com/html/. I don't have Read access to this folder despite being an admin.

If I could get help on how to display the basic wp-admin, wp-content, or just help on how to upload pictures, that'd be great

Comment: If you don't have wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes, or a wp-config file, WordPress isn't installed there. Sounds like you need to look in a different folder. Usually there's an "httpdocs" or "public_html" or somewhere similar.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen once, and the solution was actually quite odd. This may or may not help. After going through all of what I thought was obvious, it ended up being a plugin conflict with a slider revolution add-on. I racked my brain for a couple of hours, then started deactivating plugins on a whim. Something with the media I had uploaded caused the issue, but I can't put my finger on it to this day. I'm aware this is an extremely unconventional answer to the question you are asking.

Ever since that crazy night, I always start deactivating plugins to determine if there may be a coding conflict.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I deactivated every plugin I have. Nothing.